# Is it possible to find a torrent that is not linked to from a site?

Tags: bittorrent

And I mean besides people explicitly choosing to share a .torrent file with each other. Here's why I'm asking. I created a torrent using videos that I downloaded from a website. As far as I know it contains material unique to the bittorrent network, which is why I made it to begin with.

I added 15 or so trackers to it, uploaded it to a site, and set it to priority seed. Within a surprisingly short amount of time it started uploading data to several people & my client showed peers and even a couple seeds from time to time. This isn't anything hot or popular. 2 weeks later the stats from the website show no downloads of the torrent. I'm aware the site doesn't appear track how many clicks on the magnet link there are, so I'll leave that possibility open there. But to all appearances it looks like no activity, with 0 seeds and 0 peers. I also uploaded one with the same trackers simultaneously which has much more statistical activity. I only say this to clarify that I trust the sites stat mechanism.

Still somehow I've seeded multiple gigs worth of data, over 10 times the amount of data that the torrent contains. How are people finding it? Are there other sources for torrents that I don't know of? Like if a torrent is announced on a network via a tracker can people just start downloading it then, using their client only without ever visiting a website?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#Technical_description -- all you need is the hash and peer-to-peer sharing enabled.

Comment: @BarryCarter Are there other usable sources of the hash without it being linked from a magnet link on a site? Like some sort of list that provides newly available hashes along w/ file name directly to a client?